# How to activate plugin only on subsites in multisite programatically

Tags: wordpress, plugins, multisite

I am trying to activate the plugin using the below function:

```
activate_plugin('akismet/aksimet.php', '', is_multisite(), false);
```

But it activates the plugin on all subsites including network active.

I want to activate the plugin only on subsites, not on the network.

Comment: You can simply install the plugin on the Network and not activate it.
Then go to your subsite plugin page and activate it (only for that specific subsite).

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can do it via code:

```
function plugin_active_on_subsite() {
    $current_blog = get_current_blog_id();
    switch_to_blog($current_blog);
    if ($current_blog === 1 ) 
    activate_plugins( 'pluginname/pluginname.php' );
    restore_current_blog();
    elseif($current_blog === 2) {
    activate_plugins( 'pluginname/pluginname.php' );
    restore_current_blog();
    }
}

add_action( 'admin_init', 'plugin_active_on_subsite' );
```

Comment: Not working, I have five sub-sites, It only activates the plugin on the first subsites 
 only.

Comment: yes, you should pass an array of ids

Comment: Where i need to pass the ids?

Comment: Chek my updated code. 
switch_to_blog does not supports arrays, you can try with an elseif structure for each blog.

Comment: I am using the same code but with foreach loop. First, I get all the subsites and loop them.

Comment: Ok, great! 
The idea is the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246364/discussion-between-hhh-and-dineshkashera).